# prime faces data table global filter is reordering the elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.2. I use a global filter. Each row also has a column for selecting actions. When filtering is on, and the user filters couple rows, I have noticed that, when I click a button, on that row, the returned row is not the same row as selected row. Selected row corresponds to the row before the unfiltered state. 
  Primefaces/JSF assigns an id to each row as such "datatable:row_number:element". The row_number is updated as the filtering goes on but when I invoke an action on the filtered row, the row selected row_number is the row before selection. See below for code sample

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{workerRotationPage.callbackList}"
              filteredValue="#{workerRotationPage.filteredList}"
              var="callback"
              widgetVar="callbackTable"
              styleClass="custom-datatable waitingCall"
              paginator="true"
              paginatorPosition="top"
              paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
              rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50"
              selection="#{workerRotationPage.callbackWorker}"
              selectionMode="single"
              rowKey="#{callback.id}"
              rows="10">
....
 <p:commandButton 
  icon="fa fa-undo"
  value="Unassign"
  action="#{workerRotationPage.execute('unassignCallbackWorker',callback)}"
  title="Unassign Worker #{callback.worker.person.formattedFirstLastName}"
  update=":mainForm:rotationTableId :mainForm:naworkerTableId :mainForm:assignPanelId"
 />
```

The object passed to execute is not the correct callback object, rather it still refers to the callback object in the same position in the old unfiltered list.

Comment: did you try without the filteredValue?

Comment: It works without the filteredValue. However since there are too many entries in the table, it is easier for users to filter then click on the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug. There seems to be no explanation, or no reason and I have seen it reported many times without any solution. I do not have time to research it on my end but I will give the link for anyone interested [Bug Report](https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/3467)

Comment: IF you point to a bug report, at least point to the correct one. GoogleCode (in general, not only for PrimeFaces) is closed (in archive mode). And if you read the last two comments there, you have a 'partial' solution. The current issue list is in GitHub

Comment: It might be in archived mode but it still is the correct one. It is the issue I am running into. Why do you think it is not the correct one? I have tried the partial solutions (such as implemeting Serializable, and such)..  They did not work for me